# Exception while retrieving schema from Informix database using Db2Client DB2Connection.GetSchema("Tables")

Tags: entity-framework-5, informix

I am getting this error when entity framework trying to get schema from Informix database:

IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/UNIX64] SQL0969N
  There is no message text corresponding to SQL error "-23103" in the message fi
le on this workstation.  The error was returned from module "IFX11500" with orig
inal tokens "".  SQLSTATE=IX000

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem temporarily solved by recycle the database service.
Still trying to find root cause of the problem as this may not be solution for every time.

Thanks
Phani

The above problem got solves after installing a patch. The problem is not exist in newer versions of Informix.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some LOCALE misconfiguration between the client and server or some problem with the client installation.
Try confirm the locale used at the database and set the CLIENT_LOCALE with compatible value.

> -23103    Code-set conversion function failed due to an illegal sequence or invalid value.
>
> Illegal or invalid characters occur in the character string. The
>   program could not execute the code-set conversion on the characters
>   that this string contains. Reexamine the input string for illegal or
>   invalid characters and reexecute the program.

If you have an alternative way to connect at the database , run this SQL :

```
select * from sysmaster:sysdbslocale
```

You will get a information like this..

```
dbs_dbsname  sysmaster
dbs_collate  en_US.819

dbs_dbsname  sysha
dbs_collate  en_US.819

dbs_dbsname  sysuser
dbs_collate  en_US.819

dbs_dbsname  onpload
dbs_collate  en_US.819
```

This links maybe can help you : [dbaccess info](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.dba.doc/ids_dba_092.htm?lang=en) , [database locale](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.glsug.doc/ids_gug_037.htm?lang=en)

Comment: Executed above query, found same results as given. I am able to connect and execute queries, but facing problem when trying retrieve schema details.

Comment: I am able to connect and execute queries, but getting above issue when trying retrieve schema details - Db2Connection.GetSchema("Tables"); Same error thrown when trying to connect using EntityFramework.

Comment: If you try run the getSchema connected at any other database (sysuser, sysmaster, sysha, etc...) , work? (just to check if this is a specific of your database)

Comment: Good idea, didn't think of this. Tried as suggested, i am able to retrieve schema for one database whose dbs_collate is en_us.57372. Does this means, client locale is also en_us.57372. Please share how to find client_locale value.

Comment: @Ceimart,  this is issue occuring only when we try to connect through DRDA port.

Comment: Well , I'm not big fan of DRDA yet... I consider it to much limited for informix users. So, I avoid use it today. Check the IBM documentation, maybe you can try something suggested there. See the first link which this [search](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/drda%20locale?scope=informix_fmy&scope=ssw_aix&lang=en) return.

Comment: At last we found that it is issue in Informix database. Seems this issue been fixed in newer version, we didn't test though.